# gsutil で、特定の ACL を持ったオブジェクトの一覧を取得したい

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

`gsutil rsync` のコマンドを用いてデータの bucket から bucket へのコピーを行った際、 ACL をこのコマンドは指定しないと、デフォルトのものになってしまうことに気付かず、結果、コピー先の bucket で ACL が混在した状態になってしまいました。

今、このACLがデフォルトで新しく作られてしまったオブジェクトたちをリストアップして、手動で(`gsutil acl set`で)訂正しようとしています。そのために、 `project-private` な acl を持つオブジェクトをリストしたいと考えています。

## 質問

あるバケットに対し、特定の ACL を持つオブジェクトの一覧を取得するには、どうしたら良いでしょうか?